# Rails: Forgot to use dependency and now I can't delete an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was unaware that I could put dependent :destroy in my model to handle destroyed objects which lead to me having a few items in my database which should not be there. I want to manually delete them now, but when I attempt to do so in the console, I get the error:

ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed: DELETE FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?

Is there a way to get rid of these without deleting the database?!

Comment: You could drop the foreign key constraint, delete the offending rows, and then re-create the foreign key...

Comment: Find what's referencing the `users` in question and delete those things first. Or add `dependent: :destroy` to the associations and delete them through the console.